# Sequential sound upon dragging

Tags: ios, swift

I've built a small Xylophone app for iPhone, which has 7 buttons, each playing its own note when touched. I want to expand its functionality, so that when a user drags their finger from top button to bottom most or other way round, all notes are played sequentially, just as they would if you dragged your finger across piano keys.

[image]

I've experimented with adding various drag gestures (inside/outside, enter/exit), but they all work with only first button that receives an action. I.e. the first sound is played when a finger is dragged outside of the first button, but when it enters the second button then nothing happens.

I was trying to connect different gestures (Touch Up Inside + Drag) into this single IBAction:

```
@IBAction func notePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    playNote(noteNumber: sender.tag)

}

func playNote(noteNumber : Int) {
    let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "note\(noteNumber)", withExtension: "wav")

    do {
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: soundURL!)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    audioPlayer.play()
}
```

Maybe separate IBActions should be created? Can anyone give me a hint on where I should be looking?

Comment: If by gesture you are referring to the buttons actions like `touchupinside`, it won't work. Have you tried pan gesture or perhaps overriding `touchesBegan`,`touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded` with your own calculation to detect which view you're currently in?

Comment: @ebby94 thanks, will try that. I’m new to mobile development and just thought there’s an obvious easy solution I was not aware of)

Answer (score 0):

Here how I worked it around:

- Expand the `ViewController` class. Check the `panView.swift` file. Here you'll create the event catcher to listen for the `Swipe Gesture Recognizer` (That you need to add previously into your main storyboard)
- Create an array of `AVAudioPlaye` objects. Initialize those objects with the path `URL` and then se them ready to play. See the `prepareSounds()` function.

More detailed explanation [here](https://github.com/duush86/Xylophone-Pan)

Let me know if you have any trouble recreating the app on your end.

Cheer!